# Need example of MovingAverage in Arduino - Don't understand the examples I found

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use the MovingAverage function.
I want to read from A0 x number of times and send the average to Digital Write 0 to Digital Write 7.  (PORTD)

I found a few examples of Moving Average online, but I don't understand them.
I think I added the MovingAverage library but I'm not sure how to invoke it.
Do I need to use an include statement? If so, where?

I want to read the voltage on A0 and average X number of times and write the result to PORTD.
All the read values will be positive and range in value from 0.45 volts DC to 4.7 volts DC.
Below is the meat of the program.

```
    void setup() 
    {
        DDRD = 0xFF;   // all bits of PORTD are outputs
        PORTD = 0xFF;  // all bits of PORTD are one
    }
  
    void loop() {
      int val = 0;  // variable to store the value read
      int analogPin = A0; //prform A/D conversion on AD0

    while(1)
    {
        val = analogRead(analogPin);  // read the input pin

        if (val >= 000 && val <= 50)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // below range use D7 error LED  
        if (val > 050 && val <= 100)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // 160 meters use D7 error LED   
        if (val > 100 && val <= 150)  PORTD = 0b11011111;  // 80 meters use D5 for 80M
        if (val > 150 && val <= 200)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // 60 meters use D7 error LED
        if (val > 200 && val <= 250)  PORTD = 0b11101111;  // 40 meters use D4 for 40M
        if (val > 250 && val <= 300)  PORTD = 0b11110111;  // 30 meters use D3 for 30M
        if (val > 300 && val <= 350)  PORTD = 0b11111011;  // 20 meters use D2 for 20M
        if (val > 350 && val <= 400)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // 17 meters use D7 error LED
        if (val > 400 && val <= 450)  PORTD = 0b11111101;  // 15 meters use D1 for 15M
        if (val > 450 && val <= 500)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // 12 meters use D7 error LED
        if (val > 500 && val <= 550)  PORTD = 0b11111110;  // 10 meters use D0 for 10M
        if (val > 550 && val <= 1023)  PORTD = 0b01111111;  // above range use D7 error LED
  
    }//endof while

}//endof main
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving average isn't that hard to understand.

You'll need the array[N] where ideal N is power of 2 (as bitshifts are in general cheaper than division on AVR Arduinos as there is no instruction for division) and next you need index variable (and you can use sum too, as it's anoyng to count int all the time)

```cpp
uint16_t array[16] = {};
uint16_t arraySum  = 0;  // assume 0..1023 so you can have at most 64 samples
uint8_t  arrayIdx  = 0;
```

And now you only have to add one measurement and count the average (might be nicer using function - but template class is best):

```cpp
int movingAvg(int newValue) {
    arraySum -= array[arrayIdx] + newValue; // remove oldest value and add newest
    array[arrayIdx++] = newValue;           // store newest and after that move index to the oldest

    arrayIdx &= 0b00001111;  // bitmasking by 15 to limit index to 0..15

    return arraySum / 16;
}
```

In the best scenario you'd also add if you have all 16 samples, but usually doesn't matter, you can just add the first measurement 16times in the setup() function...

I personally use moving average approximation - I'll just skip whole lenghty array and substract previous average value:

```cpp
uint16_t sum = 0;
uint16_t avg = 0;

void setup() {
    avg = analogRead(A0);
    sum = avg * 16;
}

void loop() {
    sum = analogRead() - avg; // add new sample, remove average value
    avg = sum / 16;  // or   sum >> 4;

    // use of avg....

    delay(xx);
}
```

It's better with template classes (when you use for example many of them), but for a sake of simplicity